# ng-if is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to use `ng-if` to show and hide some data based on tabs because I don't want all the html to be on the DOM all the time. [Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/OU1Wy6RSPNEtbYr42ghd?p=preview) what I'm trying to do. It seems the `ng-if` is working only when the page is loaded, after that on the click of the sub tabs, it's still updating the scope variable, but I don't see the change on the UI. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ng-href="#"` from your links.  This is all you need:

```
<li ng-repeat="subTab in tabData.SubTabs">
    <a ng-click="subTabClicked(subTab)">{{subTab.Name}}</a>
</li>
```

With `ng-href` present, `currentTabId` is being updated on a child scope for each tab. On the parent scope, where `ng-if` is watching, `currentTabId` was never changed.

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/ISwjaWKggdbGL38BW078